# Who is HaRam in Tosafos

Tags: rabbis, rambam, rishonim, tosfot

I've seen `הר"ם` quoted in Tosafos in a few places. One example is [Kiddushin 50a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.50a.8?lang=bi), Tosfos **[ד"ה היה לו](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.50a.8?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Kiddushin.50a.8.1&lang2=bi)**. I always assumed it was Rabbeinu Meir, the son in law of Rashi, whose sons are the famous trio of Rabbeinu Tam, Rashba"m and Riva"m (M in the last two standing for Meir).

Recently someone told me that it's not crazy for Tosafos to quote the Rambam, and showed me an example in Zevachim.

Now, I saw in Kiddushin 47a that the Tosafos Ri HaZaken quoted הר"ם and is clearly referring to Rambam. Is this the same for regular Tosafos?

Related question is I saw [Tosafos in Kiddushin 75a ד"ה כותי](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.75a.19?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Kiddushin.75a.19.1&lang2=bi) quote הר"מ, not using a final Mem. Is this the same person?

Comment: It is important to remember who authored which Tosafot. The Rosh for example, frequently quotes Rambam. The first two or three generations of Tosafot rarely do. || In short, besides for ר"ת, don't assume that because one Tosafot refers to someone as ר"מ that a random different Tosafot does. || Don't forget R. Moses of Coucy, aka the Semag, a student of a student of Ri.

Comment: הרב משה מקוצי בעל ספר מצוות גדול

Comment: הוא כתב גם תוספות

Comment: רוב התוספות הם תוספות טוק,  אבל תוספות רבי ו פרץ היה תלמיד מהר"ם מרוטנבורג

Comment: "Tosafot Ri HaZaken" is actually R. Avraham min HaHar, who frequently quotes Rambam. The actual Ri HaZaken, better know as the Ri, or R. Isaac ben Meir of Dampierre, would not be quoting Rambam. || I wouldn't make too much of a closed vs. open מ as this could simply be the results of the printers.

Comment: There are also Tosfot, I don't remember if in zvachim or Nazir who wrote at sof dibur "מרדכי"

Comment: I know this is a few years later, but do you have the source in Zevachim where the Rambam is quoted in Tosfos? I just answered on the linked question that there are 3 instances (per a quote from Rav Chaim Kanievsky), and Zevachim wasn't on that list. Did you perhaps mean Menachos?

Comment: @Salmononius2 I probably meant menachos

Answer (score 3):

Many ascribe הר"ם to Rav Moshe Évreux  in mashcehes Kiddushin since many ascribe the Tosfos of kiddushin to the scholars  of [Évreux](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90#.D7.A8.D7.91.D7.99_.D7.A9.D7.9E.D7.95.D7.90.D7.9C_.D7.91.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.91.D7.99_.D7.A9.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.90.D7.95.D7.A8).

On a side note:

Tosfos in Menachos 42b writes the Rambam  like this :תפילין יש להן בדיקה. פי' בקונט' בחסירות ויתרות ואפי' הכי אין נקחין אלא מן המומחה [ל] לעבדן לשמן אבל ספרים 
ומזוזות לא בעי עיבוד לשמן **וכן פי' ה"ר משה בר מיימון** דמזוזה לא בעיא לשמה

Comment: Could you provide an example of the 'many' you refer to?