# Instances in Shas where Tosfos quotes the Rambam?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rambam, rishonim, tosfot

I'm aware of one instance where Tosfos quotes the Rambam:

[Menachos 42b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.42b?lang=bi)- Tosfos *dibbur ha'maschil* "[תפילין יש להן בדיקה](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.42b.15?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Menachot.42b.15.2&lang2=bi)" where right at the beginning we see Tosfos write "**וכן פי' ה"ר משה בר מיימון**".

Are there any other instances in Shas where Tosfos quotes the Rambam? (or vice verse)

Comment: A quick search on Sefaria indicates that this is the only place in Tosfos where the word מיימון appears.

Comment: @DonielF thanks! Sefaria search bar works for you? Hasn't for me in a long time/ if not ever https://twitter.com/alicht/status/1103558716912254977 also- he can refer to the Rambam without using "מיימון" either by acronym, or well known *shita* that's attributed to him, or another mechanism

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77698/who-is-haram-in-tosafos

Comment: I disctinctly remember Tosfos referring to the Rambam as ר״מ במז״ל (R' Moshe ben Maiman z"l), although I cannot remember where the Tosfos is. The Ran in numerous places uses this acronym to refer to the Rambam; I can't find the Tosfos now. I think it may have been in Kesuvos/Yevamos.

Comment: Does this include the Tosfos HaRosh? If so Bava Metzia i think 43a.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to a quote from Rav Chaim Kanievsky, there are only 3 places in Shas where Rambam is mentioned in Tosfos (brought down in the stories at the end of the 29th chapter of the Artscroll English Orchos Yosher, Page 400. Including the 2 already mentioned for the sake of completion):

1: [Berachos 44a, Dibur Hamaschil על העץ ועל פרי העץ](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.44a.13?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Berakhot.44a.13&lang2=bi) :

> ובס' המיימוני מצריך להזכיר בה מעין המאורע בשבת ובי"ט

2: [Kesubos 86a, Dibur Hamaschil לאשה לא יהבינן לה מ"ט יותר משהאיש רוצה לישא אשה רוצה לינשא](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.86a.7?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Ketubot.86a.7.1&lang2=bi)

> וכן רב אלפס ורמב"ם.

3: [Menachos 42b, Dibur Hamaschil תפילין יש להן בדיקה](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.42b.15?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Menachot.42b.15.2&lang2=bi)

> וכן פי' ה"ר משה בר מיימון דמזוזה לא בעיא לשמה

Interestingly, all three locations refer to the Rambam in a different wording, so one would be hard pressed to find them through a common search term.

Comment: Shkoyach! Thanks for sharing 

Comment: "Interestingly..." That's just another proof that there were many authors of the Tosfos not just one person.+1

Answer (score 9):

Tosefos to [Berachos 44a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.44a.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), s.v. [על העץ](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.44a.13?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Berakhot.44a.13.1&lang2=bi), cites the ספר המיימוני.

> ובס' המיימוני מצריך להזכיר בה מעין המאורע בשבת ובי"ט

Comment: Thanks! Presumably the Rambam right? (I mean how many "ספר המיימוני" 's could there be?)