# Was there correspondence or references between the Rambam and any baalei tosfot?

Tags: rambam, tosfot

The Rambam lived at the same time as many baalei tosfot, including Rabbeinu Tam, albeit on different continents. I am wondering if there was any correspondence or references between the Rambam and the baalei tosfot?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100441/instances-in-shas-where-tosfos-quotes-the-rambam/

Comment: There is a famous correspondence with the Rabbis of Lunel ,can be found online

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104230/did-the-rambam-or-the-ramban-correspond-with-tosafists