# Tosfot quoting the Ri Migash?

Tags: rishonim, tosfot, masechet-yevamot

Tosfot in [Yevamot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.83b.13?lang=bi&with=Tosafot&lang2=en) [83b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=83b&format=text) seems to address the comment of Rabbi Yosef Ibn Migash on Baba Batra.

> ול"ג דתניא כמו **שגורס הרב אבן מאגש** ואומר דתניא גבי בכור דלא היה לו לרבא להניח המשנה ולהביא הברייתא שאין להוכיח ממנה ואין להאריך

There are two orthographies in Tosfot, the first is "ר''א בן מאגש", in this case the rav is not Yosef Ben Migash but perhaps, Avraham or Eliezer, the second in Shas Oz Vehadar is "הרב אבן מיגש" and in this case he is probably the Ri Migash. An other difference is the name "מאגש" and not "מיגש", suggesting that the name is Magash and not Migash.

But I searched in BB 140b in the Chidushei Hari Migash and it matches, he has the Girsa Detanya, as Tosfot attributes to the Rav Migash.

If it is the case that Tosfot were aware of the Chidushei Hari Migash, it's surprising. I am almost sure that this is the first time that I see a citation of the Ri Migash in Tosfot. Additionally, it's surprising that Tosfot had the Ri Migash and [almost don't cite the Rambam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100441/instances-in-shas-where-tosfos-quotes-the-rambam), who was more widely known and lived approximately 50 years afterwards.

I am interested to know if this Tosfot is examined by scholars, and if they say that it's the Ri Migash, and if the Rav Ibn Migash is quoted in other Tosfotim.

Comment: Tosfot quotes rambam several times so we know that at least later tosafists where aware of Spanish scholars. Further, ri migash was a talmid of Rif, who is quoted extensively In tosefos. Why does ri migash surprise you more.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100441/instances-in-shas-where-tosfos-quotes-the-rambam

Comment: I simply don't remember citations of Ri Migash, indeed, I know that Rif is extensively quoted. For Rambam perhaps one time in Betsa, I don't remember exactly.

Comment: See intro to modern tshuvot ri migash that multiple ways to spell his name. Also, since they are quoting him it is likely they at least knew of some other quotes.

Comment: Tosfos didn't have the Rambam? https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.44a.13?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Berakhot.44a.13&lang2=bi